# how to delete items on selecting item through listbx

Tags: c#-4.0, .net-3.5

I am making desktop application using C#.NET and SQL SERVER 2008.i have taken a listbox in a form containing elements which is fetched from database.Now i want that on selecting the item which is present in the listbox should get delete I have taken a delete button
 i have listbox name listbox1 containing items and btndelete to delete

Comment: are you talking about deleting from the database also?  If so, posting a little of your database select code would help, otherwise the question is too general for a decent answer on the db part.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a button click handler that will delete the currently selected item in the listbox:

```
btnDelete_Click( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    listBox1.Items.Remove(listBox1.SelectedItem);
}
```